# 'self' not defined when using a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I know that there are a bunch of similar questions on here but none of them seem to be having the problem that I am.  Here is the code.

```
class Tournament(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Tournament, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.games = [Game(eval('self.combo' + str(i), globals(), locals())) for i in range(1, 15)]
```

when I run it I get 'NameError: name 'self' is not defined' on the last line.  I printed the locals() before and during the list comprehension and it shows 'self' before the list comprehension but not inside it.  So I tried saving it to a temporary variable

```
class Tournament(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Tournament, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        loc = locals()
        self.games = [Game(eval('self.combo' + str(i), globals(), loc)) for i in range(1, 15)]
```

and I get the same error on that last line.

Can anyone tell me what's happening here?  I was able to work around it with a regular 'for' loop, but I'd really like to understand why it won't work this way.

---

Edit: Adding full error message from the second example

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tournament.py", line 55, in <module>
    interface = Tournament()
  File "tournament.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.games = [Game(eval('self.combo' + str(i)), globals(), loc) for i in range(1,15)]
  File "tournament.py", line 48, in <listcomp>
    self.games = [Game(eval('self.combo' + str(i)), globals(), loc) for i in range(1,15)]
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

---

Edit 2:
I am more confused than ever.  I tried to write a stripped down example that would get the same error but I'm unable to get the error again.  So I thought it was something to do with PyQt, so I stripped all the dependencies on PyQt just to see if the error went away, but it still comes up!

### I'm probably spending way too much time on this since I have a workaround, but it's driving me crazy.

Edit 3.  Minimal example, as requested

```
class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, combobox, next_game=None):
        self.combobox = combobox
        self.next_game = next_game

class Tournament():

    def __init__(self):
        self.combo1 = 1
        self.combo2 = 2
        self.combo3 = 3
        self.combo4 = 4
        loc = locals()
        self.tournament = [Game(eval('self.combo' + str(i)), globals(), loc) for i in range(1, 4)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interface = Tournament()
```

Comment: What is the point of `self.setupUi(self)`? Please also extract and provide a [mcve]. As new user, take the [tour] and read [ask] as well.

Comment: What is the point of `eval`? It certainly looks as a contorted piece of code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The `combo` are combination boxes that are automatically generated and named by Qt Designer (combo1, combo2, combo3, etc).  the `eval` is turning the string into code.  I couldn't think of a simpler way to loop through all of them

Comment: *"so I stripped all the dependencies on PyQt just to see if the error went away, but it still comes up!"* Please could you post a [mcve] - i.e. a short piece of code which reproduces the error without the dependencies on PyQt? I'm not able to reproduce the error in your second example (I didn't try using PyQt). It would also help to `print(loc)` before the list comprehension to confirm that `self` is in there.

Comment: @Sean In your MRE, you have a `)` in the wrong place in `eval('self.combo' + str(i)), globals(), loc)`. It should be `eval('self.combo' + str(i), globals(), loc))` so that all three arguments are for the `eval` function. If I make that edit, then the error goes away when I test it. Is it possible that your original code also had the same problem?

Comment: There has to be a way of doing this without `eval` and `globals()`.

Comment: @AMC There is - you can use `getattr` or `self.__dict__` (or change the design to use a list/dictionary). But the interaction of the list comprehension, `eval` and `locals()` is a curious problem worth investigating!

Comment: @kaya3  How embarrassing.  What a rookie mistake.  Sorry for wasting your time.  At least I learned that list comprehensions have their own scope.

Comment: @Sean Oh, no worries at all - at least you solved the problem!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `locals()` inside a list comprehension doesn't do what you want it to:

```py
>>> x = 12
>>> locals()
{..., 'x': 12}
>>> [locals() for i in range(1)]
[{'i': 0, '.0': <range_iterator object at 0x0000000003034DD0>}]
```

Notice that `x` is in the dictionary when `locals()` is called from the current scope, but not when `locals()` is called from the list comprehension. The reason is that the comprehension is executed in its own scope, so that `x` is not local in that scope. On the other hand, the variable `i` used in the comprehension *is* local in the comprehension's scope, for example.

The direct solution to your problem is to assign `init_locals = locals()` in the correct scope, then pass it to the comprehension. Unfortunately, `init_locals` won't contain `i` from the comprehension, so we need to pass a dictionary containing both `init_locals` and the comprehension's `locals()` to be able to use both `self` and `i`:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tournament, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        init_locals = locals()
        self.games = [
            Game(eval('self.combo' + str(i), globals(), { **init_locals, **locals() }))
            for i in range(1, 15)
        ]
```

A simpler option is to use `getattr` instead of `eval`:

```py
        self.games = [
            Game(getattr(self, 'combo' + str(i)))
            for i in range(1, 15)
        ]
```

By the way, if you have to use `eval` (or, to a lesser extent, `getattr`/`setattr`) to initialise a class instance, then your design should be reconsidered. If you need to access different `combo`s dynamically by an index `i`, better to store them in a list or dictionary which is designed for dynamic lookups by index or by key.

Comment: I believe that's what I already did (second code block), or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @Sean *"Unfortunately, init_locals won't contain i from the comprehension, so we need to pass a dictionary containing both init_locals and the comprehension's locals() to be able to use both self and i:"*

Comment: Also the `combo` are automatically generated and named, so I'd have to add them to a list one at a time, at which point I might as well just initialize each `Game` individually.

Comment: You could add them to a list or dictionary using a very similar comprehension; if anything the comprehension would be simpler since it avoids the `eval` and `getattr` functions. For example, `self.combos = { 'combo' + str(i): ... for i in range(1, 15) }`. Or even simpler, `self.combos = { i: ... for i in range(1, 15) }` so that you don't need to keep writing `'combo' + str(i)` everywhere else.

Comment: `init_locals` (or `loc` in my case) is only used for the `eval` so it doesn't need to contain `i`

Comment: I see. In that case, the error is probably that `self.combo1` or one of the other attributes doesn't exist, and you're getting an `AttributeError` from the `eval` because of it. Please edit your question to include the full error message in the second case.